# What does the Decorative property on MS Shapes DO?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, ms-office

I'm considering using the Shape.Decorative property for a particular function I'm writing (MS Powerpoint and Excel VBA)  But, I'm trying to find out what this flag is natively used for in MSO? Can't find anything meaningful in my searches.
Can anyone explain to me what the native MSO functionality (Excel and Powerpoint, primarily) is for this shape property?
(Using 2019 if that helps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's related to accessibility:

https://davidberman.com/how-to-alternative-text-for-decorative-images-in-microsoft-office/

Comment: So, MSO does nothing with it. It's simply for exporting to other formats. Thx.